# NextJS: TailwindCSS not working in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I’m using NextJS, TailwindCSS and Typescript. When running in development, everything works as expected, but when running in production, no tailwindcss classes are applied. Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/Capsule-app/next.

Answer (score 0):

This problems occurred because of Purge. Please check the [official page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production)

Few possible way to fixed this issues.
Option A (Quick & Dirty Plus Lazy) :
In `tailwind.config.js` file try `purge: false`

Option B:
If you are using `purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],` Or If you have custom css class or third-party lib class then [follow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#purge-css-options) [Safelisting](https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html) with  `install @fullhuman/postcss-purgecss first then try

```
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
   plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
      ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
         ? {
              '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss': {
                 // added sections folder and changed extension to jsx
                 content: ['./src/components/**/*.jsx', './src/pages/**/*.js'],
                 defaultExtractor: content =>
                    content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
              },
           }
         : {}),
   },
}`
```

Note: Each solution depend on it's context. I request to you read official docs carefully.

Comment: Setting purge to this: `purge: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/modules/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],` worked for me

Comment: Any reason why sometimes when running `yarn build` the build will fail with `error Command failed with exit code 3221225477`, but when I run `yarn cache clean`, it fixes it?

Comment: @alexover1 Dose your TailwindCSS issues solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I had issue where height class of tailwind working fine in **dev env** but in production it wasn't working.

Fix..

Open **tailwind.config.js** Inside **module.export** add all folders that contain tailwind class like this

```
module.exports = {   content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./layouts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",   ],  };
```

I created layout folder and added some layout here with tailwind css. But this wasn't added in config file thats why i was having this issue . Issue fixed after adding layout folder in config files.

Note
layout folder was added in root directory outside of component or pages folder