# TailwindCSS not working in production - NEXT JS

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

I have made an app for production. During development I used `tailwindcss` with `postcss` and `autoprefixer` packages. `Tailwindcss` was working in development but when I deployed it to production it didn't worked. I tried to reinstall tailwind and other packages but still it didn't worked. I also tried to change path in `tailwind.config.css` file but still didn't worked. I don't know what I am doing wrong! Here is my config files of `tailwindcss` and `postcss`

I am using Heroku hosting


#### tailwindcss.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

#### postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: { config: "./tailwind.config.js" },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

#### Global Styles

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the TailwindCSS plugin point to `./tailwindcss.config.js` in your `postcss.config.js`?

Comment: @juliomalves I tried removing it but still it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```js
const { join } = require('path');
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

and same for tailwind.config.js

```js
 important: true,
 content: [join(__dirname, 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue,html,css}')]
```

if it didnt work try alternative [source](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration)

```css
@config "./tailwindcss-config.js";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't worked

Comment: try again i edited exports

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here

> [NextJS: TailwindCSS not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480197/nextjs-tailwindcss-not-working-in-production/76400555#76400555)

I had issue where height class of tailwind working fine in **dev env** but in **production** it wasn't working.

Fix..

Open **tailwind.config.js** Inside **module.export** add all folders that contain tailwind class like this

```
module.exports = {   content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./layouts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",   ],  };
```

I created layout folder and added some layout here with tailwind css. But this wasn't added in config file thats why i was having this issue . Issue fixed after adding layout folder in config files.

Note layout folder was added in root directory outside of component or pages folder